# Randomization software/service for clinical trial

Tags: clinical-trials, random-allocation

I need a software/web-based system for the clinical randomization. This software/service should have the capabilities for handling stratification, multiple centers and block. The sample size of patients is about 300-500. It is best that it is free but a low price is also acceptable.
I googled but did not get any useful results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you didn't come across [Sealed Envelope](http://www.sealedenvelope.com/) when you googled. We provide online randomization services for clinical trials with stratification and random permuted blocks etc. There is a [simple service](https://www.sealedenvelope.com/simple-randomiser/v1/) that is free for up to 50 randomizations (and free to students for larger trials). Contact me directly if you need any help setting it up (I'm the founder and a statistician).